# How to setup the default browser to follow hyperlinks

Tags: external-command, navigation, mouse

On a text file with a hyperlink (`http://url/`) if I hover the mouse over the hyperlink and click on it, it is opened on chrome. How can I change the browser that vim decides to use when following hyperlinks, so that I can change the default web browser to firefox?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708956/1924583

Comment: @Tumbler41 This is to open the file I am editing on a web browser, but not in order to open a url address that is part of the text of my file. Say my file is :  "[text] http://example.com  [more text]" At the moment, if I click on `http://example.com`, vim will open that url on chrome. I want vim to open it on firefox.

Comment: You'll probably have to change your default browser on your system.

Comment: Oh, I did it already! My default browser is firefox, but vim uses chrome, for some reason

Comment: I suspect Vim is not involved and the terminal is handling the click event. You can try `gx` in normal mode to open a file or an URL in your browser (via the native `netrw` plugin).

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a problem with `urxvt`. On a `gnome-terminal` the urls are opened in firefox. I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (as you've figured out) it's not actually anything to do with Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [LEI](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/12003/lei) commented, the problem resided on my terminal, and it didn't have anything to do with vim. Changing the corresponding parameters of my terminal fixed the issue.